# Inverted index in Lucene

Tags: lucene, inverted-index

I want to know which class in *Lucene* generates the *inverted index*?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inverted index is created in a class named `FreqProxTermsWriter`, based on information retrieved from documents, such as *term frequency*, *document frequency*, *term position* etc.

Comment: Exactly in *appendPosting* function

Answer (score 1):

An [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) is the structure of the data files that [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) uses. There's not really any particular class that *makes* it inverted. The classes in the [`org.apache.lucene.index`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/src/java/org/apache/lucene/index/) package manage the files that ultimately make the data structure an inverted index.

Comment: I know that,but *lucene* first read each document as set of fields and process fields with same name together, after that write each new field in a buffer. I want to know what does it do after this??

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down some lucene fundamentals

An index contains a sequence of documents.

- A document is a sequence of fields.
- A field is a named sequence of terms.
- A  term is a string

so Field when added to documents, if they are inverted they are indexed, note that fields can be both indexed and stored

So invert(indexed) operation happens at the field level and yeah  [Field](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html) is a class which is where i think inversion happens

Comment: Your answer has potential and contains some useful information but there are some typos and grammar issues that make it hard to understand. Please correct and maybe clarify. (My downvote will be removed/changed to upvote if fixed.)